# avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding after serial

Tags: serial, avrdude

I have searched but have not found any solution to my problem so I am asking it here.  I make a program in python that makes serial communication with the Arduino. I started to upload my Arduino code but I forgot that my python program was open in the terminal (I use Ubuntu). So, I think the Arduino code and python output went to the same port which the Arduino is on. After that I couldn't upload any code into the Arduino.

Every time it prints the following error:

> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
>   avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

and then makes more 9 attempts.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Likely all you really need to do is exit/kill every process trying to use the Arduino, un-plug it from the USB port, and plug it back in.

This is in part because Linux doesn't really block multiple programs from trying to use the serial device at the same time, unless they take particularly efforts to claim it exclusively, but the attempted sharing may result in serial traffic that doesn't make any sense.

Another issue can be that if a still-running program was using a device that vanished, when that device is reconnected it will not be assigned to the in-use port number, but to a free one.